# how can I change the value of text every x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span which has nothing in it and I want to change the value of it every x amount of seconds. I've tried this, but the code only executes the`if` and it doesn't execute the `else if` nor `else` statements.
html:

```
<span id="text"></span>
```

jquery:

```
var text = null;
var step1 = "Step1";
var step2 = "Step2";
var step3 = "Step3";

$(document).ready(function(){
    text = $("#text").append(step1);
    setInterval(change, 2000);

});

function change(){

    if(text.val = step1){
        text.empty().append(step2);
    }else if(text.val = step2){
        text.empty().append(step3);
    }else if(text.val = step3){
        text.empty().append(step1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting variables rather than comparing:

```
if(text.text() == step1){
    text.empty().append(step2);
}else if(text.text() == step2){
    text.empty().append(step3);
}else if(text.text() == step3){
    text.empty().append(step1);
}
```

`=` is variable assigment operator
`==` is comparision operator

Note: You use `.val()` when you must get value of input. Use `.text()` to get element's content.

Comment: Ad it should be `.val()` not `.val`

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried .val() before, but it wasn't working. Seems that I needed to put .text() instead of .value(). Thanks again.

Comment: Try `.text()` instead as my example does.¨

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't limit yourself to an implementation that explicitly checks values between a fixed number of items. If you use the `%` operator, and look up the initial text index in an array, you can easily scale this out to *n* items:

```js
(function(){

    var element = $("#text");
    var strings = ["Step 1", "Step 2", "Step 3"];
    var present = $.inArray(element.text(), strings);

    setInterval(function advance () {
        element.text(strings[++present % strings.length]);
    }, 1000);

}());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AZLJN/3/

And, for kicks, an animated journey through the above solution:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is helpfull, but what I need at this moment is just for those three, but thanks anyway I'll use it in the future.